# this mount point is invalid. The /root directory must be on / file system

Tags: linux, partition, centos

I'm preparing CentOS 6.5 x86_64 system with following mount points

```
/usr/local – 10 GB or more ***
/var       – 10 GB or more ***
/root      – 200 MB or more ***
/tmp       – 200 MB or more ***
```

The mount points are created successfully but the system does not allow me to complete installation and issues an error:

```
this mount point is invalid. The /root directory must be on / file system
```

Comment: When this error came ? What is the command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of the Anaconda installer in the Centos 6.5 repository is 13.21.215-1.

By checking out that source code, we can see that the installer has sanity checks for the storage configuration (starting at 1008 of `storage/__init__.py`).

Part of those sanity checks assert that the following directories must be on the root filesystem and thus cannot be on separate mountpoints

```
mustbeonroot = ['/bin','/dev','/sbin','/etc','/lib','/root', '/mnt', 'lost+found', '/proc']
```

If you remove the separate mount you have created for /root (perhaps allocate the space to your / pointpoint if possible), the installer will likely allow you to continue.

Answer (score 2):

please create a partition as / .

/ partition should be minimum 4.5 Gb in size.

Under / all directory will be created.

Comment: The OP clearly wants separate mountpoints for some of his directories. The point is to understand why `/root` cannot be placed on a separate partition not to put everything on the same. And where does that `4.5Gb` come from exactly? In which way is it relevant here?

Comment: @lgeorget, I suppose the installer complains that there's nothing mounted on `/`. You need a root filesystem in any case.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Sorry! I haven't noticed that the OP doesn't have a `/` mounting point.

Comment: Agreed, looks like you need a / to start with.